# Installing a package using pip or easy_install with ipython / conda

Tags: python, ipython, package, anaconda

I'm trying to install 'frida' on my Anaconda environment, and although it installs fine, I keep getting an error when importing it from IPython:

```
In [4]: import frida
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-58e5c65e5010> in <module>()
----> 1 import frida

ImportError: No module named frida
```

On the normal python shell the import works fine. The problem is only with IPython.

I've tried using easy_install from the conda command line - no go.

I've tried this from an IPython shell:

```
In [5]: easy_install.main( ["-U","frida"] )
```

And the package install successfully, but IPython still gave an error when importing it.

pip doesn't find the package.

I seem to be missing something with the IPython packages - How does one install packages to IPython?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in virtualenv, then installing `IPython` into virtualenv resolve such problems.

Usually, IPython is giving this advice when it start inside of virtualenv.

Comment: I'm using Spyder editor, which has a IPython shell. Can I run this shell in virtualenv?